# MongoDB how to $project aggregate with multiple $sum?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

For MongoDB, need to group on event and supply multiple attribute fields.

My purpose is to show for a group the associated field attributes together with a list of sum totals from numeric fields.

For the MongoDB the aggregate has $group and $project. $project can show fields listed within the $group.

My $group is working fine by itself, e.g, without the $project. When I supply $project before or after the $group, I receive the following error:

```
query failed: (Location40323) A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.
```

My code is as follows:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            eventName: "$EVENT_TYPE",
            registeredDate: "$BEGIN_DATE_TIME",
            stateName: "$STATE",
            damageCosts: "$DAMAGE_PROPERTY",
            peopleCosts: "$DEATHS_DIRECT",
            injuriyCosts: "$INJURIES_DIRECT",
            cropCosts: "$DAMAGE_CROPS"
        },
        $group: {
            _id: "$EVENT_TYPE",     
            totalPropCost: {
                $sum: "$DAMAGE_PROPERTY"
            },
            totalDeaths: {
                $sum: "$DEATHS_DIRECTY"
            },
            totalInjury: {
                $sum: "$INJURIES_DIRECT"
            },
            totalCropCost: {
                $sum: "$DAMAGE_CROPS"
            }
        }
     }
])
```

Alternately: attempted to use the $push command, and it looks like a valid run with $push:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$EVENT_TYPE",     
            totalPropCost: {
                $sum: "$DAMAGE_PROPERTY"
            },
            totalDeaths: {
                $sum: "$DEATHS_DIRECTY"
            },
            totalInjury: {
                $sum: "$INJURIES_DIRECT"
            },
            totalCropCost: {
                $sum: "$DAMAGE_CROPS"
            },
            events: {
              $push: {
                  name: "$EVENT_TYPE",
                  date: "$BEGIN_DATE_TIME",
                  state: "$STATE"
              }
            }
        }
     }
])
```

I use the following sample of data for this mongoDb query, which without the $project, works correct on $sum.

```
[
  {
    "BEGIN_YEARMONTH": 201007,
    "BEGIN_DAY": 7,
    "END_YEARMONTH": 201007,
    "END_DAY": 7,
    "END_TIME": 1630,
    "STATE": "NEW HAMPSHIRE",
    "YEAR": 2010,
    "EVENT_TYPE": "Heat",
    "BEGIN_DATE_TIME": "07-JUL-10 12:51:00",
    "END_DATE_TIME": "07-JUL-10 16:30:00",
    "INJURIES_DIRECT": 0,
    "DEATHS_DIRECT": 0,
    "DAMAGE_PROPERTY": "0.00K",
    "DAMAGE_CROPS": "0.00K"
  },
  {
    "BEGIN_YEARMONTH": 201001,
    "BEGIN_DAY": 17,
    "END_YEARMONTH": 201001,
    "END_DAY": 18,
    "END_TIME": 1500,
    "STATE": "NEW HAMPSHIRE",
    "YEAR": 2010,
    "MONTH_NAME": "January",
    "EVENT_TYPE": "Heavy Snow",
    "BEGIN_DATE_TIME": "17-JAN-10 23:00:00",
    "END_DATE_TIME": "18-JAN-10 15:00:00",
    "INJURIES_DIRECT": 0,
    "DEATHS_DIRECT": 0,
    "DAMAGE_PROPERTY": "0.00K",
    "DAMAGE_CROPS": "0.00K"  
  }
]
```

Comment: What is the desired output? Group events by EVENT_TYPE or by the STATE?

Comment: both: EVENT_TYPE and by STATE, oh source, separate queries...

Answer (score 0):

For this investigation, after many tries, and other ideas welcome, especially using alternative solutions with $project. By and by, this much is giving me adequate results. The $push command appear to work best. If anyone knows how to get a $project working, please advise and provide explanation. For now, $push work on one solutions for group and list of attribute fields.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$STATE",     
            totalPropCost: {
                $sum: "$DAMAGE_PROPERTY"
            },
            totalDeaths: {
                $sum: "$DEATHS_DIRECTY"
            },
            totalInjury: {
                $sum: "$INJURIES_DIRECT"
            },
            totalCropCost: {
                $sum: "$DAMAGE_CROPS"
            },
            events: {
              $push: {
                  eventName: "$EVENT_TYPE",
                  CzName: "$CZ_NAME",
                  cZTimeZone: "$CZ_TIMEZONE",
                  eventDate: "$BEGIN_DATE_TIME",
                  eventMonth: "$MONTH_NAME",
                  state: "$STATE",
                  observer: "$SOURCE"
              }
            }
        }
     }
])
```